# App crashing after splachscreen [Xamarin Forms]

Tags: android, xamarin, plugins, xamarin.forms

I added the ImageCirclePlugin (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin) to my Xamarin Forms project and after that my app crash after the splashscreen. It shows the error NullReferenceException, as you can see below:

[image]
[image]

I didn't write any code using the plugin.

I already tried to uninstall the nuget but nothing changed.

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.LayoutRootPage (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity activity, Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height) [0x0007a] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:279 
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IPlatformLayout.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00003] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:196 
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x0000e] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\PlatformRenderer.cs:73 
   at Android.Views.ViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <b45497bae7b44aa5b84d9841d4f92a20>:0 
   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:fd5f91d5-8d2a-4d55-bc22-8073570fcfd7 (intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you have initialized the plugin? After the `Forms.Init(this, bundle);` command on the platform code you should initialize the renderer: `ImageCircleRenderer.Init();` (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin#setup)

Comment: I uninstalled the plugin. Why the error still happens?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I installed the plugin again and use the ImageCircleRenderer.Init(); on the MainActivity. It runs now, but the page is frozen and I cannot interact with it. Any solution?

Comment: `The page is frozen` is not enough information to help you to solve it. Share some code related to it.

Comment: I didn't add any code. I just installed the nuget on PCL and Android, and put the ImageCircleRenderer.Init(); in the MainActivity. What is happening is that I'm running the project and on my login page which was working fine before, I'm not able to interact with the components. I click on an entry or a button and nothing happens. The events are not being triggered.

Comment: clean your project and rebuild

Comment: I did it. Still not working. Really don't know how to solve this. The output is Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
The thread 0x2 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Is any reference corrupted on your projects?

Comment: Everything was working fine. It stops when I installed ImageCirclePlugin. I don't think any reference was corrupted.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza você é brasileiro. Cara, realmente não sei o que está acontecendo. Agora que instalei novamente o plugin, a tela fica literalmente congelada. Não consigo interagir com nada. Nenhum evento é disparado. Já teve alguma experiência assim?

Comment: Don't think, just check it out anyway one more time. When you install a new package, sometimes others are updated and it can break the app

Comment: How do I check if my references are not corrupted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164516/discussion-between-diego-rafael-souza-and-giorge-caique).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

The current version of ImageCirclePlugin messed up with my project. I don't know why. I installed the version 1.8 and everything is working fine now.